# grails 1.1.1 will support java 1.7

Tags: java, grails, websphere

Currently my application is running on grails 1.1.1 with java 1.6 on web sphere server. My application is working in old server with java 1.6.Recently server team upgrade the websphere server 8.5.5 and they asked us to deploy an ear with java 1.7. I have deployed the ear with java 1.7. now I am getting below error:

```
Error Page Exception
SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.


Original Exception: 
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [charEncodingFilter]: could not be initialized
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
Error Stack: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsControllerClass 
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:426) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1704) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:411) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653) 
     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477) 
     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603) 
     at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:667) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:611) 
     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269) 
     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1261) 
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:426) 
     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:92) 
     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1255) 
     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1093) 
     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:832) 
     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814) 
     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335) 
     at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118) 
     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228) 
     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181) 
     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247) 
     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360) 
     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602) 
     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$QueuedWork.run(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1981) 
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsControllerClass 
     ... 43 more 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
     ... 43 more 
     Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [customer.CustomerController]! 
     ... 43 more 
     Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type CustomerSegment not present 
     at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:399) 
     at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:126) 
     at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:84) 
     at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:68) 
     at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1164) 
     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:428) 
     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:175) 
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:456) 
     at customer.CustomerController.$getStaticMetaClass(CustomerController.groovy) 
     at base.BdwBaseController.<init>(BdwBaseController.groovy) 
     at customer.CustomerController.<init>(CustomerController.groovy) 
     ... 43 more 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CustomerSegment 
     at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:302) 
     ... 54 more
```

I have a few questions:

- Grails 1.1.1 will support java 1.7?
- if not do I need to upgrade grails?
- What are all the steps to upgrade grails?
- web sphere 8.5.5 will not support java 1.6?
- to resolve this error what I need to check?
- Do I need to update jars?

please find below jars which I am using in my application:

[jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNy7w.jpg)

Comment: One question per question

Comment: I didn't get you @BurtBeckwith

Comment: Burt is reminding you to ask one question per post.  It's kind of impossible (or at least really confusing) to answer everything you're trying to ask here.  As a sidenote, you're also asking about some really old (2009) stuff here, and even if you do get it to work, you're better off upgrading for a large number of reasons including performance, security, and maintainability!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to try to answer as much as I can, but it's a best-effort since you're asking way too many questions in one post!

1 - Probably not.  Grails 1.1.1 came out in 2009, and Java 1.7 came out in 2011, and was a major change over 1.6.  You might be able to force them to work together, but you're going to struggle to find good information six (plus) years later.

2 - Yes.

3 - You can start here: http://docs.grails.org/1.2.0/ and go from there.

4 - See comment below.  (Originally I said, but was wrong: IBM recommends Java 8 with WebSphere 8.)

5 - Probably not important, if you're upgrading everything anyway.

6 - Yes.

Comment: For point 4, WebSphere 8 will only run with Java 6.  WebSphere 8.5.5, which the customer was asking about, has differing java versions based on what fixpack level within 8.5.5 is being used.  For any recent fixpacks (8.5.5.5 and newer) Java 6, 7, and 8 are supported (although Java 8 is recommended).  However, it is worth noting that IBM will be withdrawing support for Java 6 in 8.5.5 on April 30, 2018.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!  I just did a quick google search and clearly got that point wrong!

Comment: Thanks you for your support. I will try to update my grails. Daniel & Alex Motley

Comment: Good luck!  Post questions on StackOverflow as you go if you run into problems; Grails 1 is pretty old but I'm sure there are people here who will help if they can!  I started on Grails 1.2 a few years ago, and am finishing up an upgrade to 3.2 now, so it's definitely possible!

Comment: last question:
to which version I need to upgrade of grails? @Daniel

Comment: I would at least try to get to something in the 2.x line; 2.5.latest is good.  If you can go all the way to 3.3 you'll be current which is good for long term support, but upgrading is difficult and takes time.  I would recommend going no more than a major version at a time (don't try to go from 1 to 3!) and reading the upgrade notes in the grails docs along the way.  There are good instructions usually, for things like "1.1 to 1.2" and then "1.2 to 1.3" but probably not "1.1 to 2.5", so you'll have to read and kind of figure out for yourself the best path at this point.